# Using un-exported function from another R package?

Tags: r, cran

I often use utility type functions from other packages that are un-exported:
`pkg:::fun()`. I am wondering if I can use such a function within new functionality/scope in my own R package. What is the correct approach here? Is including the package in my description file enough?

Comment: You could "borrow" it.  `borrowedfun <- pkg:::fun()` and put the package in Suggests.  Making sure the original author is okay with it is a good idea.  Or just ask them if you can just use the exact function in your own package.

Comment: You can of course ask them or just include the function based on the license of the other package.

Comment: If it's only a single function from the package, why not just copy it? Of course, check the licence, make a note in the functions documentation and perhaps even email the author. As a comparison, I assume you have code you found on SO in your package?

Comment: IIRC the use of `:::` is *not* allowed in CRAN packages. You should ask the original package author to export it, or, alternatively, permission to include a copy in your own package.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Summarising comments from @baptise, and etc...:
- `:::` not allowed on CRAN, so options:

  1. ask author to export it so you can use it in your package via standard imports or suggests.
  2. copy / lift a version of it and clearly cite within your package.

Answer (score 37):

Another trick is using [`getFromNamespace()`](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/getFromNamespace.html):

```
fun <- utils::getFromNamespace("fun", "pkg")
```

The only advantage over `:::` is that you don't get any NOTEs and it's allowed on CRAN. Of course, this is not good practice as a hidden change in `pkg` can break your package.

*Note:* With [roxygen2](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/) you have to add the `utils` package to the `Imports` field of your `DESCRIPTION` file to fulfill CRAN's requirements. Alternatively, you can put it in your `NAMESPACE` manually.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked perfectly. Eliminates need to copy/paste function from other package.

Comment: Is this practice still permitted on `CRAN` in 2022?