# I am receiving the error: 'could not find function "stripAttributes" Why is this?

Tags: r

After installing merTools and using its library, Rstudio tells me it could not find the function.

```
library(merTools)

mysurvey <- stripAttributes(mysurvey)
```

Comment: Are you sure ``stripAttributes()`` is still an available function in the ``merTools`` package?

Comment: Doesn't look like it's exported https://github.com/jknowles/merTools/blob/c5039ee0c48bd75d6deba23c9d8fce498510fa29/R/merData.R#L22

Comment: Seems like the function is not to use by user in the package (at least in  v.050). Edit : Like Dason said, seems like an internal function or something like that.

Comment: You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535773/using-un-exported-function-from-another-r-package)