# How do I use tidyselect "where" in a custom package?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use `where` in my own R package. I was going to use it in the code as `tidyselect::where()` but the function is not exported. For this same reason, you cannot use `@importFrom tidyselect where`.

I do not want to reference it with `:::`. The code will work if I simply refer to it as `where()`, but then I receive a note in the checks.

> Undefined global functions or variables:
>        where

What is going on here? I assume the function works as is since it it captured as an expression in my code, and tidyeval knows how to handle it on evaluation?

**Example**

As an example, if you start a clean R session, the following will work (dplyr 1.0.0) without running `library(dplyr)`. It clearly knows how to handle `where`.

```
dplyr::mutate(iris, dplyr::across(where(is.numeric), ~.x + 10))
```

Likewise, this will also work, but I do not want to use it in a package. So I use the above, which gets flagged in `devtools::check()`.

```
dplyr::mutate(iris, dplyr::across(tidyselect:::where(is.numeric), ~.x + 10))
```

**Question**

How do I use `where` from `tidyselect` in a package without it being flagged as undefined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using un-exported function from another R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32535773/using-un-exported-function-from-another-r-package) The top answer there explains how to use unexported functions from other packages in a way that CRAN allows (which should get rid of your R CMD check flag)

Comment: Yes and no. Yes in that it does appear to be a solution. No in that it seems a bit tedious for the tidyverse. Given how they are all about making things easier, having to do something like that for what should be commonly used function going forward seems a bit odd. So my assumption now is that they either (a) have a smoother recommended way (i.e., I am doing something wrong) or (b) perhaps intended to export and it may be helpful to bring it up as an issue. I thought I would ask here because somebody usually knows.

Comment: See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/issues/201) where this is discussed. They have purposefully not exported it, for now, because `where()` is such a general name that they were reluctant to do so initially, but admit they will likely do so eventually. They allude to a workaround for the R CMD check issue, but to me it seems likely to refer to the same workaround as I linked to

Comment: @duckmayr since you posted there has been more discussion on the issue, and `utils::globalVariables("where")` is what they recommend.

Comment: Good news - since tidyselect 1.2.0 `where()` is exported https://github.com/r-lib/tidyselect/releases/tag/v1.2.0

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There is an existing workaround for this type of problem. One of the items that *is* exported from `tidyselect` is a list of helper function called `vars_select_helpers`. This includes `where`, so if you do

```
mutate(iris, dplyr::across(tidyselect::vars_select_helpers$where(is.numeric), ~.x + 10))
```

You should get the same functionality without any grumbling from the check tools.